# Will a user still be punished if their historical bad behaviour/sock-puppeting is later discovered?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, account-suspension, sock-puppets

Imagine a user has two accounts on the same site. But after a while, they remove one of the accounts.

I don't know if it's still discoverable that a user once had a second account on a site but if the answer is a 'yes', then will the user still be punished for the former wrongdoing?

Of course, imagine it was just done because their account got banned from asking questions. Not for upvoting their posts on another account.

Comment: A new wrongdoing might trigger a new user behavior review. The "punishment" is not because of past wrongdoing but because they didn't stop. First, the disciplinary measures, like a temporary ban or suspension, are intended to tell the user that the wrongdoing should stop, not to cause harm. The reversal of the reputation wrongly earned is not a punishment, it's just a fix to something that should not have occurred

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "still punished"? Stack Exchange doesn't have a [statute of limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations), but there *can* come a point where an infraction is so old it's just not worth pursuing, in the judgment of a moderator. Usually takes quite a while to hit that point, though.

Comment: @Rubén So if the wrongdoing won't happen again their past wrongdoing would be forgiven?

Comment: @SnackExchange Since there is already a Staff participating here, I suggest you wait for their reply/answer. You might want to make a comment mentioning Slate to notify them that the question was edited to address their comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Communities shown in your profile. Whatever I could say will be based on sites that might have different cultures and moderators with very different points of view (tolerance, sensibility, etc.)

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not permissible to do with multiple accounts what you can't do with one account.

Comment: @Slate How am I able to see the numbers for both up-votes and down-votes on my post? (5 ups and 10 downs) Isn't it a later privilege?

Comment: And also other people's posts

Comment: @SnackExchange On The Meta only the bar is 100 rep for that, not 1K.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your 'other' account was actually removed, there's generally nothing for us to do - votes are invalidated (and that's a big thing) and often posts deleted.

If not

If you *did* do something naughty, and you believe no one noticed, and you feel remorse, or at least a slight fear of getting found out, you could request an account merger *explaining* the full extent of the situation, flag your own posts or send up a contact request, doing the same, and basically giving the person handling it the information to clean up the situation with less work.

> Our general strategy is to discourage specific problem behaviors, not individual users.

<sub><sup>(from [a day in the penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/))</sup></sub>

We're not generally likely to dig up past accounts unless we notice a current issue *ongoing*. We might annotate the two accounts for *future* action, but if its something old, suspending or otherwise acting on an account might not necessarily create a change in behaviour, if its already stopped.

In this case you've identified, either for the right or wrong reasons that a behaviour is problematic. Its ok to reach out and *make it right*. I'm pretty sure owning up to past mistakes is grounds for appreciation, not punishment.

Comment: Mods aren't machines, also. If you _do_ get suspended (you're more likely to get a warning first, regardless), and you explain the situation politely, they may/may not unsuspend (it is just a week for a 1st time after all), but they probably won't hold it against you in the future. Esp if it doesn't happen again

Comment: We might potentially even not notice :D